# Select with a Group By and Order by Date

Tags: mysql, sql

My table `orders`:

```
ID (int pkey) | store_id (int fkey) | order_category (int fkey) | order_price (deci 10,2) | date (date)
```

---

```
1 | 123 | 5 | 10.25 | 2-11-2021
2 | 678 | 2 | 10.25 | 2-10-2021
3 | 123 | 5 | 10.25 | 2-08-2021
4 | 123 | 3 | 10.25 | 2-04-2021
5 | 678 | 2 | 10.25 | 2-01-2021
6 | 123 | 1 | 10.25 | 2-01-2021
...
```

I'm trying to get the most recent `order_price` for each `order_category`.

```
SELECT order_price FROM orders
WHERE store_id = 123
GROUP BY order_category
ORDER BY date
```

But it seems `ORDER BY date` is not working when `GROUP BY` is applied. The result I would like is:

```
1 | 123 | 5 | 10.25 | 2-11-2021
4 | 123 | 3 | 10.25 | 2-04-2021
6 | 123 | 1 | 10.25 | 2-01-2021
```

Using MySQL `8.0.23`

Comment: Please provide sample data as well as desired and actual outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a subquery for max date grouped   by category

```
select o.order_price, t.order_category
from orders 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT order_category, max(date) max_date
     order_price 
    FROM orders
    WHERE store_id = 123
    GROUP BY order_category
) t on t.order_category = o.order_category 
    AND t.max_date = o.date
ORDER BY date
```

Answer (score 2):

Use window functions!

```
SELECT o.*
FROM (SELECT o.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY order_category ORDER BY date DESC) as seqnum
      FROM orders o
      WHERE store_id = 123
     ) o
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT order_price,
  x.order_category
FROM orders
JOIN (
  SELECT order_category,
    MAX(`date`) AS `date`
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY order_category
) AS x USING (order_category, `date`)
```